# Display data in gridview base on rbac role in yii2

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, rbac

How to display records in gridview in yii2 using rule created for roles, in RBAC ?

Suppose, there is two roles "admin" and "agent".

Now the requirement is;

1. In grid for agent, display only client which is assigned to that
   agent.
2. For admin, grid will show all client list.

Comment: Please share the research you have already done / what you've tried so far / where you are at right now.

Comment: you can manage it via searchModel too

Answer (score -1):

```
    Here the example I am using this in my code 

    // User.php  -> Model 

        public function getUserRolesAsArray($userId)
        {
            $roles = Yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser($userId);
            if (!empty($roles)) {
                foreach ($roles as $role) {
                    $userRole[] = $role->name;
                }
                return $userRole;
            }
        }
    // view.php -> view file 

                        [
                            'label' => 'Role',
                            'value' => $model->getUserRoles($model->id) ?? null,
                        ],

Kindly try this i think this may be help you
```

Comment: Thanks, but its not that I was looking for!

Answer (score -1):

It is done,

I have to create a permissions that will given to role, and based on that permission, DataProvider query is modified